# dyld: Symbol not found: _PyBaseObject_Type

Tags: c++, macos, boost, boost-python, macos-catalina

I'd like to use the Boost library in my C++ code, so I've inputted the right include search path and the right library search path, then I added all the Boost library files in Xcode. When I build my code the compiler says that the build is successful. However, once I run the code, the console tells this:

**Console:**

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _PyBaseObject_Type
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libboost_python27.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/lib/libboost_python27.dylib
Program ended with exit code: 9
```

**My code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/any.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Where is my mistake? Please help.

Comment: Boost is not library, it is quite huge set of libraries. Usage of boost::any feels pointless since any was added to C++ by C++17 as std::any. So just include <any> and use std::any.

Comment: @ÖöTiib `any` is just an example. The errors raise with any library.

Comment: If it is with every library then it is apparently issue with how you install libraries or incorporate these into your projects. Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix for common causes of that.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you solve this?

Comment: @ZackLee yeah, but I don't so like the solution. I just installed Boost via homebrew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs when you don't add a package to your project the right way. The problem has resolved in my example by installing Boost via Homebrew. Installing the package the right way means that if you install it manually (e.g. downloading it from GitHub), you should install it on the right path. But I suggest always installing C++ packages via Homebrew.